# What does "mission mixing" mean for long-range aircraft?

Tags: terminology

I know very little, like long-range aircraft will be used for short-range and medium-range operations. But what is the purpose of using them like that? Also I want to get complete details of "mission mixing" in layman's terms.

Comment: Can you please give a source for the term?

Answer (score 1):

Mission mixing appears to be running computer *simulations* (or other probabilistic analyses) to assess aircraft engine components' reliability also under non-typical or non-designated use. All for the purpose of design or maintenance/inspection strategies, I would assume.

So, mission mixing is not something you would purposely do with actual aircraft. (Or maybe you would, but then it is not called mission mixing.)

Here are a few articles mentioning it:

https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/pdf/10.2514/1.13142
https://asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/GT/proceedings-abstract/GT2012/44731/439/247656

http://en.cnki.com.cn/Article_en/CJFDTotal-HKXB902.017.htm
https://www.astm.org/DIGITAL_LIBRARY/STP/PAGES/STP14812S.htm

Comment: Anecdote: In 2018, when Air Berlin stopped flying, the German Lufthansa flew from [Frankfurt to Berlin with sixty B747-400](https://www.businesstraveller.com/business-travel/2017/09/29/lufthansas-b747s-fly-frankfurt-berlin/). They said it didn't pay off but it was the easiest way to accomodate all the passengers between FRA and TXL. The "program" stopped after five months.